# Adding specification by month for Order by publisher?

Tags: sql, date, count, entity

This is the code I have come up with so far:

```
SELECT Publisher.publisherID, Publisher.publisherName, COUNT(Publisher.publisherID) AS SalesCount  
FROM orderLine JOIN
     Book      
     ON orderLine.ISBN = Book.ISBN JOIN
     Publisher     
    ON Book.publisherID = Publisher.publisherID    
Group By Publisher.publisherID    
Order By COUNT(Publisher.publisherID) DESC;
```

However the concept of date functions is still lost on me, and I am struggling to think of a way to implement it. To be clear, the tables involved are:

```
orderLine **orderLine,** orderNum, ISBN, productID  
Book **ISBN,** authorID, publisherID, genre, bookPrice  
Publisher **publisherID,** publisherName, contact
```

The Order table which has not been added to the join is what contains the date.

```
Order **orderNum,** customerID, orderDate, orderTotal
```

Thus far, when I ran the query on a sample database, I got back a column containing publisherID, publisherName, and then a column with the total number of sales in which each publisherID appeared in the orderLine table, sorted so that the highest "seller" of books appears at the top. Now I am faced with the issue of further sorting that number, by month.

Comment: You should tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Does that query really execute? Seems invalid to me.

Comment: How does it seem invalid?